# Gerund and causal clause

Tags: verbs

I know that the Italian gerund can be used in temporal, hypothetical, concessive and modal clauses, but I have just read the following sentence:

> Partendo domani, ti ho comprato un regalo.

Is this idiomatic? If so, does gerund express cause here? Is that usage of gerund as usual as the expressions "siccome", "dato che", "visto che", "poiché" ?

Comment: Can you share the source of the Italian sentence? It almost sounds as an imperfect translation from another language...

Comment: I have read the sentence in a comment in an Italian language learning tool, therefore I am not sure if it is correct. Source: https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/335070

Comment: Thanks. Gerund may well have causal uses, but this particular sentence doesn't sound like one of the first two or three ways an Italian would phrase it.

Comment: Have you considered trying reading actual Italian texts (novels, newspapers, comics, children books, whatever suits your tastes and level) rather than random snippets on the web?

Comment: @DaG, thanks for clearing it up! I suspected that sentence was wrong because the corresponding sentence in Portuguese (my native language) sounded odd too. I assume the problem in it is that the verbal tense of the main clause does not agree with the semantic tense expressed by the verb in gerund form? In this sentence, the former uses past and the latter expresses future. If both represented future events, the sentence would be fine. Example: Partendo domani, ti farò piangere.

Comment: @DaG regarding my learning methodology, I have already learned a language using only a dictionary, a grammar book, books, newspapers and movies. That method works fine, but I have reached the conclusion that focusing in the first months of learning in memorizing the list of most used words (by creating simple sentences with them), translating practical sentences, learning basic grammar, hearing blogs/movies and talking often with natives is the most effective way to get from scratch to conversational in a few months without attending a language course. Duolingo helps me with the translations.

Comment: I've been learning Italian for almost 2 months, I am near the end of the Duolingo Italian tree and I see a fast evolution with this learning method. Of course, as soon as I finish that, I'll follow on with traditional text/audio/video sources, such as newspaper, books and movies. Sorry for the off-topic and thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Thank you, sincerely, for giving an insight on your learning methods. I was under the impression that you had a more random approach to learning Italian and I apologise for that. That said, personally I am a bit skeptical about tools such as Duolingo, but of course everyone knows which methods are the best ones for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently studying gerunds with an Italian teacher in Lucca Italy. Based on my last weeks lesson, the example you gave partendo (leaving tomorrow with because or since inferred)does express cause which can be expressed by either using a gerund as it did in this sentence or using a conjugated verb plus dato che, perché, siccome, visto che or poiché. The choice is yours.